# GPU not detected every 4 days

Tags: gpu, hardware-detection

My `Galax GTX 1650 Super EX-1 Click OC PCI-E` after 1 year+ of use, suddenly after BSOD , and not able to detected by Motherboard, but surprisingly after few days probably 4 days+ it can detected by motherboard again, (My Motherboard (B450 AORUS M) LED indicator VGA lights up when not being detected) so far I experienced 2 times, means it is now apprx. 10 days past, it not detected no matter how I tried, only leave it for quite a few days without boot it , then it can boot up again, after I run play some game , restart or try remove replug GPU on, it goes undetectable again. My MB got 2 PCIE slots, tried both and no luck. I have non-modulus PSU, 2 cables of 6+2 pin power supply tried both and no luck as well.

(Edit: I bought another low spec display card Gigabyte GeForce GT710, and it has no problem at all right after i switch it from my Galax card)

I guess now 99% I pretty sure the issues are come from GPU it self, because I no need change anything and it can be boot after few days.
Could anyone can figure such weird issue is caused by what component within GPU?

Comment: Do you have another computer that you can try the card in? It *could* be caused by something like a capacitor or MOSFET going bad, in which case you might be able to get a replacement under warranty.

Comment: A GTX 1650 Super is more than a year old (more like 3). When you experience this behavior, without a GPU, how do you use your machine?

Comment: @andrew-morton hmm I actually would like sent for servicing center nearby for troubleshooting but unfortunatly because of pandemic makes this hard and my country is full locked down beside food and vaccination

Comment: @ramhound i got laptop

Comment: [How do you have a desktop GPU inside a laptop?](https://www.galax.com/en/graphics-card/16super-series/galax-geforce-gtx-1650superex1clickoc.html) you made no mention of this being a laptop. [B450 AORUS M](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-M-rev-1x#kf) is also a desktop product.  The details in your question do not reflect this being a laptop.  Due to your question not being clear I am compelled to vote to close your question.

Comment: Could be a power supply issue.

Comment: @ramhound u were asking me "how do i use my machine when i experience this issue" , so i answered u, "i use my laptop as a backup", i meant, it can't even boot due to gpu not detected. How do i even use???

Comment: You should simply edit your question to make all that clear, I consider myself pretty intelligent, and I was certainly confused by your comment

Comment: @andrewmorton I forgot to mentioned, i just get one GT710 from online shopping, and it has no problem at all, does it still possible to be caused by component on mobo?

Comment: @mokubai, about power supply, can it be explained why it must be at least 3 days to be working?

Comment: @ramhound my entire question was talking about desktop, i was confused by your first comment, I'm not sure what u actually asking. Are u asking me , How do I use my machine before all this behavior happened? Or after all this behaviour, I remove GPU and I actually not using it anymore.

Comment: @elliotching If you get the graphics card to the state where it stops working, you could put it in a plastic bag, pop it in the fridge for an hour, let it warm up *in the bag* for half an hour (to avoid condensation on the card), and see if it magically starts working. If so, it might just be a poor solder connection somewhere, but it would need someone suitably experienced to fix it.